# SwiftUI: How to set iPad keyboard type to the equivalent of decimalPad in iOS (small)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to know is it possible to access the same style of the keyboard as a decimal pad (`.decimalPad`) on iOS. Inside the Settings, Face ID & Passcode, an iPad presents a small-sized keyboard (see attached image). Is it because the presented view is small, and the keyboard automatically adjusts according to it?

P.S. Taking a screenshot removes the keyboard from the image.
[image: iOS Settings]

Comment: Are you able to implement this ..?

Answer (score 0):

*It is not possible to change the keyboard layout in **swiftUI**, but you can do it in **UIKit**.*

---

## UIKit

> ## keyboardLayoutGuide
>
> A layout guide that tracks the keyboard’s position in your app’s layout.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/3752221-keyboardlayoutguide/

#### Sample  code

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/keyboards_and_input/adjusting_your_layout_with_keyboard_layout_guide

#### WWDC video

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10259/